# How to fill a word document using Visual Basic / Visual C# in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, export-to-word, mergefield

I'm looking for options to fill a Word Document from either Visual Basic, or Visual C#. I'm currently using merge fields, and the code below to fill specific fields in a Word Document, but now I've run into a situation where I need tabular data pushed to MS Word. Is there anyway to take data from a grid view (number of rows is dynamic), and import it into a Word Document Table using a merge field or something of that sort? I have to maintain the format of my template doc, and would like to be able to control the layout of the page ..

```
            Dim templateDoc As String = Server.MapPath("\Userfiles\docs\" & location)
            Dim mergePath As String = Server.MapPath("\App_Data\Temp\")
            Dim mergeFileName As String = location.Replace("/", "_") & ".docx"
            Dim mergeDoc As String = mergePath & "\" & mergeFileName

            File.Copy(templateDoc, mergeDoc, True)

            Using pkg As Package = Package.Open(mergeDoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)

                Dim uri As Uri = New Uri("/word/document.xml", UriKind.Relative)
                Dim part As PackagePart = pkg.GetPart(uri)

                Dim xmlMainXMLDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
                xmlMainXMLDoc.Load(part.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))

                Dim innerXml As String = xmlMainXMLDoc.InnerXml _
                                         .Replace("«Corporate Legal Name»", businessName) _
                                         .Replace("«Address 1»", mailingAddress1) _
                                         .Replace("«Address 2»", mailingAddress2) _
                                         .Replace("«City»", city)
                xmlMainXMLDoc.InnerXml = innerXml

                Using partWriter As New StreamWriter(part.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
                    xmlMainXMLDoc.Save(partWriter)
                End Using

                pkg.Close()
            End Using
```

Comment: I hope this code solution has no limit of 255 replacement fields as mail merge in Word docx document has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like my answer for your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141040/how-to-fill-an-excel-template-using-asp-net-vb-or-c/6246747#6246747) regarding Excel, [Office writer](http://www.officewriter.com/index.aspx) will work for you here too!

Answer (score 2):

You can write out in HTML and save it with a .doc extension and Word will handle it gracefully.

Comment: Do you have any examples? Would I have to write out the HTML for the entire document? That seems like it could be quite time consuming, and would require a lot of code...

Comment: Why not replace some other merge field with an html `table`?

Comment: I was hoping that's what you meant... so if I had a grid view, couldn't I use HTML writer to output the gridview html to the merge field? Is there any way of styling?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether it would maintain it's style, but will give it a try. Thank you.