# How to fill an excel template using ASP.NET, VB or C#?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, fill, excel-template

I have a an excel file that has been manually populated, and now needs to be automatically populated using ASP.NET, vb or c#. I've been looking around, and have found examples on how to export a gridview, and data to excel sheet, but not anyway to maintain the format of the original template. I've recently populated a word document using merge fields... does excel have anything similar? Could I break the file down into XML and use that as a template? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there particular cells that need to be populated or is the text free from with data needing to be inserted inside of cell data

Comment: Here is an example, the top left portion of the excel file has ... Requested By : <<name will be filled here>>, Customer Name : <<name here>>, Pick up mode <<mode here>>, then below is a table of products that will need to be populated including fields like product code, name, desc, cost, margin, price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Office Writer](http://www.officewriter.com/index.aspx) from soft aritsans will do exactly this. Plus a lot more it is extremely powerful and I have used it to great effect in the past.

The down side is that it is rather expensive!